# How to use browser's console by PowerShell

Tags: powershell, automation

I am trying to use the browser's console (F12) by PowerShell script, As i need to run a query code on the browser over my script, is this possible to open the developer tools then the console to write the query code, all this over PS?

Note: i need this as i tried to click on a button on the web page but i get error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression." i searched a lot for a solution with no chance, so now i am trying to use the mentioned button query "on-click query" and i need to send this query to the browser as a work around instead of pressing the button, the button query looks like " return WebsiteScripting.Export.getExport().start('QueryModel', 'ReportGridHiddenField', 'Excel', this)"

my code to press the button:

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("URL")
$ie.visible = $true
#Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) 
{ 
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000; 
}
$doc = $ie.document
$btn = $doc.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById('id') | Where-Object {$_.innerText -eq 'Export'}
$btn.click()
```

And i also tried:

```
$btn = $doc.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById('id')
```

And:

```
$btn = $doc.getElementById('id')
```

with no chance, still get the mentioned error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."

thanks in advance

Comment: "As i need to run a query code on the browser over my script" - can you elaborate on the kind of query you want to execute here? Perhaps you're trying to do something that you don't actually need a browser for...

Comment: i am trying to click on a button on the web page but i get error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression." i searched a lot for a solution with no chance, so now i am trying to use the mentioned button query "on-click query" and i need to send this query to the browser as a work around instead of pressing the button, the button query looks like " return WebsiteScripting.Export.getExport().start('QueryModel', 'ReportGridHiddenField', 'Excel', this)"

Comment: You need to run some code to get that error. Please [update your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70590762/edit) with the code in question

Comment: Please show us the relevant part of the HTML. If the button you seek actually has an `id`, then `getElementById()` should find it. If not, you may need to use `getElementsByTagName()`, `getElementsByName()` or `getElementsByClassName()` and use an extra Where-Object to filter the specific item.